# Prevent InAppBrowser from visiting specific links

Tags: cordova, phonegap, inappbrowser

I'm using Phonegap to create a simple app for my client whose main feature is to give their customers access to a Sharefile portal via the Inappbrowser. Apple recently denied my app submission because there is a link in the app that takes the user to a page that has links to download Sharefile's program on other platforms (Windows, Android, etc) which is against Apple's terms of service (no linking to 3rd-party applications).

Is there a way to prevent the Inappbrowser from opening certain links, sort of like a url blacklist? I have no control over removing the link that takes users to the app downloads page but is there a way to just deactivate the specific url from opening or being visited?

Comment: No way, but you could create your own download site by parsing the official sharefile portal.

Comment: Create my own download site? Are you taking downloading the Sharefile webpages and hosting them in my app?

Comment: Create an PHP script, which you are hosting on your server. This script parses the Sharefile webpages and outputs just the files/links your customer wants. Your app is pointing to your PHP script and that's it.

Comment: That's honestly a bit much given this particular scenario, as the company i'm building this for is only paying me to get a basic main page and open the inappbrowser to their Sharefile portal using Phonegap/Cordova. I guess this is my only option if things get to that point, so thank you for the suggestion.